# I'm try using Spotify PHP api

Tags: php, api, spotify

I'm try to use api from

https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php/blob/main/docs/examples/access-token-with-authorization-code-flow.md.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work well because it gets such an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPIAuthException: Invalid redirect URI in D:\Software\Development\XAMPP\htdocs\spotif\auth\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php:56 Stack trace: #0 D:\Software\Development\XAMPP\htdocs\spotif\auth\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php(244): SpotifyWebAPI\Request->handleResponseError('{"error":"inval...', 400) #1 D:\Software\Development\XAMPP\htdocs\spotif\auth\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php(112): SpotifyWebAPI\Request->send('POST', 'https://account...', 'client_id=48f0c...', 'HTTP/2 400 \r\nda...') #2 D:\Software\Development\XAMPP\htdocs\spotif\auth\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Session.php(250): SpotifyWebAPI\Request->account('POST', '/api/token', Array, Array) #3 D:\Software\Development\XAMPP\htdocs\spotif\auth\app\check.php(26): SpotifyWebAPI\Session->requestAccessToken('AQA9X84L0SDucXG...', 'a86937efa85589a...') #4 {main} thrown in D:\Software\Development\XAMPP\htdocs\spotif\auth\vendor\jwilsson\spotify-web-api-php\src\Request.php on line 56

I tried to solve the problem with all methods,but even if in the console of my Spotify application.

I have everything set up well, like the redirect URI in my PHP code, I still get an error.

Changing the redirectURI doesn't help me in any way.

Comment: And just to confirm, the redirect URI is the same as the one in developer.spotify.com when you created the application?

Comment: Yes Redirect UI, is same to Spotify Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wait some hours/days fixing my problem**